# why so many Avast listening processes show up on netstat?

Tags: tcp, netstat

I'm running Mac OSX.  when  I ran 
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"

I'm getting all these processes, is it normal?
launchd       1           root   26u  IPv6 0xc2e82557abee8b81      0t0    TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
launchd       1           root   27u  IPv4 0xc2e82557abeeab89      0t0    TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root    3u  IPv4 0xc2e82557b1f273a1      0t0    TCP localhost:12080 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root    4u  IPv6 0xc2e82557abee8741      0t0    TCP localhost:12080 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root    5u  IPv4 0xc2e82557b2c5db89      0t0    TCP localhost:12443 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root    6u  IPv6 0xc2e82557abee8301      0t0    TCP localhost:12443 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root    7u  IPv4 0xc2e82557b2c5d3a1      0t0    TCP localhost:12110 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root    8u  IPv6 0xc2e82557abee7ec1      0t0    TCP localhost:12110 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root    9u  IPv4 0xc2e82557b2c5eb89      0t0    TCP localhost:12143 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root   10u  IPv6 0xc2e82557abee7a81      0t0    TCP localhost:12143 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root   11u  IPv4 0xc2e82557b2c5e3a1      0t0    TCP localhost:12995 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root   12u  IPv6 0xc2e82557abee7641      0t0    TCP localhost:12995 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root   13u  IPv4 0xc2e82557b2c5fb89      0t0    TCP localhost:12993 (LISTEN)
com.avast   375           root   14u  IPv6 0xc2e82557abee7201      0t0    TCP localhost:12993 (LISTEN)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be normal behaviour - Avast uses local proxies [for some of its services (e.g. Web Shield and Internet Mail)](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=37684.0).

For example, if you're browsing through the web, the data you download from webservers will be analyzed by Web Shield before it is transferred to your browser.

For more details, you may also ask in the [community forum](https://forum.avast.com/).

PS: On my computer (Windows OS) there are also a few listening ports belonging to avasts process.